# Pointer Handling and Valgrind approach in ARM architecture

Tags: c++, embedded, arm

I am running the below code on ARM target. Below are the observations
1) The code executes without any problem/crash though the pointer is accessed without   initialization(HalloWorldMain *hm1)
2) Valgrind does not complain any memory issue on this program.

```
==344== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==344== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==344== Using Valgrind-3.9.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==344== Command: ./HalloWorld
==344==
Hallo World!
Prinitng at simpleTest
==344==
==344== HEAP SUMMARY:
==344==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==344==   total heap usage: 2 allocs, 2 frees, 8,552 bytes allocated
==344==
==344== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==344==
==344== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==344== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)

#include <iostream>
#include "HalloWorldMain.h"
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

HalloWorldMain::HalloWorldMain() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    ofstream file;
    file.open("1.txt", ios::out);
    file << "Inside the file \n";

}
void HalloWorldMain::simpleTest()
{
    cout<<"Prinitng at simpleTest\n";
}

HalloWorldMain::~HalloWorldMain() {
    // TODO Auto-generated destructor stub
}

int main()
{
    HalloWorldMain hm;
    HalloWorldMain *hm1;
    cout << "Hallo World!\n";
    hm1->simpleTest();
}
```

Can someone help me understand this behaviour. Thank you

Comment: the first thing to understand is that it won't work because hm1 is an uninitialized pointer.

Comment: It would help already if you read the assembler code that is using the pointer...

Answer (score 1):

When you call a member function of an object, the address of the object is handed over to the function as an implicit parameter. In your case, the pointer you are using to call the function is uninitialized, so the address is garbage.

But this is no problem in your case, as `simpleTest()` is not accessing the object in any way. It could just as well be a static function. As soon as you try to access a member variable though, the program will crash.

Answer (score 1):

The reasons why your program be behaves correctly is because `HalloWorldMain::simpleTest` does not access the `this` pointer of `HalloWorldMain`. In other words, `simpleTest` could be defined as static since it does not make use of the internal state of the the class.

Another way of looking at this is, that in C++ all non-virtual class functions take a `this` pointer as an explicit first parameter but is like any normal C or C++ function in all other respects. Since in your case, you never make use of the `this` pointer to access the internal state of your object, your program behaves as expected.

Were you to make `simpleTest` virtual, you would get the crash since the vTable stored in the object needs to be queried.

This may well be undefined behaviour in C++ but works as I have explained on all platforms that I know.

Comment: I changed the funtcionvoid HalloWorldMain::simpleTest() { cout<<"Prinitng at simpleTest\n"; this->crash = 8; } And the program crashed, with Segementation Fault. Thanks for the clear explanation. Now it makes sense

Comment: doron, Would it be possible to provide reference on where I can read more about such vTable handlings? Thank you!

Comment: I don't know any reference in my head. Google might help but the best way to understand vTables is to do your own implementation of polymorphism in C using function pointers.